# How to concatenate % and column name in a LIKE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT FacilityID, FacilityName, CMSProviderID, [Provider Number] 
FROM G2_Facility, SCIPHospitalCompare
WHERE [Provider Number] LIKE '%' + CMSProviderID + '%';
```

And I get:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.
```

What am I doing wrong? I saw many examples doing stuff like this but for some reason it simply does not work at all.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the data types of `Provider Number` and `CMSProviderID`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume that either `[Provider Number]` or `CMSProviderID` is a numeric field?

Convert the numeric field to a string to compare the two:

```
SELECT FacilityID, FacilityName, CMSProviderID, [Provider Number]  
FROM G2_Facility, SCIPHospitalCompare 
WHERE CAST([Provider Number] as nvarchar(50)) LIKE 
    '%' + CAST(CMSProviderID as nvarchar(50)) + '%';
```